# What could be affecting on my code to got a huge-change font-size?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, font-size

I have a code like this :

```
<p><span><span>text</span></span></p>
```

When I say the font-size in anywhere of this elements, visibility on mobile does a big change between 23px and 24px, using em and pt too.

When I use 23px, it looks well... When I update to 24px: seems like 48px or more changed.

I don't use font-size in NO element before in all document, except the base css where 1.1em is updated.

I think is anoying but I don't have another way to explain it...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsITN.png (I cannot post images yet :/ )

Comment: can you show this on fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML syntax only values 1-7 possible:

```
<font size="6">This is some text!</font>
```

CSS syntax:

```
<p style="font-size:20px">This is some text!</p>
```

You sure you writing it properly?

Answer (score 1):

see if you have og::content and you determinate **width** header